# After changing the targetPort of service, DNS URL is not working in Kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress

we have EKS cluster with version 1.24. Have nginx-controller for ingress.
Have created the Deployment and Service as follows, its a sample application.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: apache-app
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: apache-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: apache-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: apache-app
        image: httpd:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: apache-svc
  namespace: default
  labels:
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: apache-app
```

everything was working fine till I changed the targetPort. For testing purpose, I changed the targetPort to 9999 and applied the changes using `kubectl apply` command and now URL (http://abc.example.com) is failing. After that, I again changed back the port to 80 (previous one) but still the URL is not working. It means, even after rolling back the changes, URL is not working.

Not sure what is wrong. All the PODS are running.
After referring the ingress controller logs, I see that, DNS URL is still trying to connect to port 9999 but it should connect to port 80 as I have already rolled back the changes.

Do I need restart any deployment, service OR ALB?

**UPDATE 1**

**Command :**

```
 kubectl get svc apache-svc -o=jsonpath='{.spec.ports}'
```

**output**

```
[{"port":80,"protocol":"TCP","targetPort":80}]
```

**Command 2**

```
kubectl get ing
```

**output**

NAME            CLASS    HOSTS                                               ADDRESS
PORTS   AGE
micro-ingress      abc.example.com   a4bbbe78e1a68478ea345rt567yu7-518c5fa564c5ce6c.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com   80      23h

Comment: What does 
kubectl get svc apache-svc -o=jsonpath='{.spec.ports}' and
kubectl get ing

return?

Comment: please refer UPDATE